# English Tanakh with as much commentary as possible

Tags: product-recommendation, tanach, commentaries, chumash

I am looking for a Tanakh Sefer (or set) which has as much commentary as possible. I’m basically looking for one place where I can study without opening a thousand other seforim.

Comment: Being in English as a requirement makes this more challenging as being in English means lots more words to fit on the page. There are a lot of options for Tanakh with commentary in English but none that are going to look like a mikros gedolos exactly.

Comment: @Dude Except, you know, [mikraot gedolot in English](https://jps.org/product-category/collections/the-commentators-bible-the-rubin-jps-miqraot-gedolot/).

Comment: https://sefaria.org

Answer (score 4):

The [ArtScroll Tanach Series](https://www.artscroll.com/Categories/tan.html) may be what you're looking for. Personally, I have found the amount of commentary to be a bit overwhelming, but there's a substantial amount of material in there.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have looked at this series before and find the commentary to be very difficult to follow as it is not in any sort of format, rather just on thrown together. I have seen a number of Hebrew versions which breaks down each commentary by the Rabbi with a subheading etc... I was hoping to find something like this

Comment: Just to note that not the entire Tanakh is available in this series. –

Answer (score 2):

Try [Alhatoraha.org](https://alhatorah.org). In the settings, check the box for English translations. Any commentary with an English translation will automatically display it.

Answer (score 1):

[Al hatorah](https://alhatorah.org) is probably your best bet but there are still options if you need hard copies, though none of them are complete. There's the [JPS Commentator's Bible/Mikraot Gedolot](https://jps.org/books/the-commentators-bible-5-volume-set/) but that's only on chumash. The Judaica Press Tanach does cover the whole bible but the English commentary is a digest not a direct translation of each commentary.